# Limit and Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $x_{n}\to (0,0,-1)$ as $n\to\infty$.
Moreover, let $(M_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a positive sequence such that $M_{n}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
Assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_{n}\text{dist}(x_{n},\partial B(0,1))<\infty$. Is it possible to construct a counter example so that $M_{n}(1+x_{n}^{3})\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$? (Here, $x_{n}^{3}\to-1$ as $n\to\infty$).

I have tried with some concrete examples like $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=((\frac{1}{2n^{\alpha}},0,-1+\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for some $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $M_{n}= n$. However, apparently it is hard to find suitable $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$.

Is my premise wrong in the first place? (This means, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_{n}(1+x_{n}^{3})<\infty$)

Any suggestion or hint is pretty much appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Is $x_n^3$ the third component of $x_n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the bad notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$x_n:=\left(1-\frac1{n^3}\right)\cdot\left[\sin\!\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}n\right),0,\cos\!\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}n\right)\right]\in B(0,1).$$
Then $\operatorname{dist}(x_n,\partial B(0,1))=\frac1{n^3}$. However $$1+x_n^3=1+\left(1-\frac1{n^3}\right)\cos\!\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}n\right)\sim\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}.$$

Take $M_n:=n^3$.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! YOU, MY FRIEND, HAVE HELPED ME!
This is brilliant! Thank you very much! This means a lot for me!